# Can $U(n)$ be constructed as a countable union of proper Lie subgroups of $U(n)$?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, unitary-matrices

Can $U(n)$ be constructed as a countable union of proper Lie subgroups of $U(n)$ for any $n$?

As I see it, the obvious answer is "no", since the dimension of the Lie algebra for any proper subgroup of $U(n)$ must be strictly less than $\dim\mathfrak{u}(n)$, meaning that the dimension of the subgroup must be strictly less than the dimension of $U(n)$, and a smooth manifold of dimension $d$ cannot be covered by a countable union of submanifolds of dimension $k<d$.

Is this intuition correct, or am I missing something critical?

(Also, if any of my terminology here is in error or seems awkward, I'd appreciate a heads up. With thanks.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. More generally, no differentiable manifold can be written as a countable union of closed submanifolds of smaller dimension. This, together with the fact that $U(n)$ is connected (which imples that no subgroup of $U(n)$ has the same dimension of $\dim U(n)$), is enough to prove what you want to prove.

Comment: I suppose this follows pretty quickly from the fact that $\R^{n+1}$ is not the union of countably many $n$-dimensional subspaces, which is nice and concrete.

Comment: A submanifold is not, in general, a vector subspace. I would would use the fact that every manifold is locally compact and therefore a Baire space. So, it cannot be written as a countable union of closed subspaces with empty interior.

Comment: I was thinking about the tangent space at a point of the big manifold. But my idea doesn't make much sense now that I think about it.

Comment: We're not supposed to post 'thanks' comments, but: thank you. I always appreciate the expertise on this site.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.